# Compute the pairwise distance between each pair of the two collections of inputs in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two collections. One consists of *m<sub>1</sub>* points in *k* dimensions and another one of *m<sub>2</sub>* points in *k* dimensions. I need to calculate pairwise distance between each pair of the two collections.

Basically having two matrices *A<sub>m<sub>1</sub>, k</sub>* and *B<sub>m<sub>2</sub>, k</sub>* I need to get a matrix *C<sub>m<sub>1</sub>, m<sub>2</sub></sub>*.

I can easily do this in scipy by using [distance.sdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) and select one of many distance metrics, and I also can do this in TF in a loop, but I can't figure out how to do this with matrix manipulations even for Eucledian distance.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37040451/1586200)?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar thank you but no. That question solves the problem when A and B are the same. Basically this is a partial case of my problem because they calculate pairwise distance between each pair in one collection.

Comment: In that solution, if you replace `a[j]` with `b[j]`, I think you will get what you want or am I missing something? The only caveat is you will have to make `A` and `B` of same size. That you can do by zero padding the matrix with smaller number of rows and then discard the rows from your result.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar I highly doubt that i can do that. Even if I can padding is not ideal because one matrix can have 1000x5, and another 10x5. Padding another one with zero might be not the best thing to do. BTW, it looks like I have found how to do it. My math currently is not rigorous, so I want to verify it for a few minutes.

Answer (score 6):

After a few hours I finally found how to do this in Tensorflow. My solution works only for Eucledian distance and is pretty verbose. I also do not have a mathematical proof (just a lot of handwaving, which I hope to make more rigorous):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

M1, M2, K = 3, 4, 2

# Scipy calculation
a = np.random.rand(M1, K).astype(np.float32)
b = np.random.rand(M2, K).astype(np.float32)
print cdist(a, b, 'euclidean'), '\n'

# TF calculation
A = tf.Variable(a)
B = tf.Variable(b)

p1 = tf.matmul(
    tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(A), 1), 1),
    tf.ones(shape=(1, M2))
)
p2 = tf.transpose(tf.matmul(
    tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(B), 1), shape=[-1, 1]),
    tf.ones(shape=(M1, 1)),
    transpose_b=True
))

res = tf.sqrt(tf.add(p1, p2) - 2 * tf.matmul(A, B, transpose_b=True))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print sess.run(res)
```

Comment: Here's another version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009647/compute-pairwise-distance-in-a-batch-without-replicating-tensor-in-tensorflow

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I thought it caclulates [pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html). Distance between elements in one group. Was I wrong?

Comment: Ah, good point. You can get pdist out of cdist by concatenating the two matrices into (m1+m2),d shape and taking the off-diagonal block of cdist which will have shape m1,m2, but I guess that's more expensive than your approach

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov btw, do you know how to calculate other metrics?

Comment: `cosine` and `correlation` is expressible in terms of linear algebra so similar approach, not sure about the other ones. For general case perhaps you can do the following: `@function.Defun` that defines f(i,j) that computes metric between example i and example j, then do `tf.map_fn` over all pairs of (i,j) and reshape the result. Personally though I would probably just use scipy, and then feed the result back into tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

This will do it for tensors of arbitrary dimensionality (i.e. containing (..., N, d) vectors). Note that it isn't between collections (i.e. not like `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`) it's instead within a single batch of vectors (i.e. like `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import string

def pdist(arr):
    """Pairwise Euclidean distances between vectors contained at the back of tensors.

    Uses expansion: (x - y)^T (x - y) = x^Tx - 2x^Ty + y^Ty 

    :param arr: (..., N, d) tensor
    :returns: (..., N, N) tensor of pairwise distances between vectors in the second-to-last dim.
    :rtype: tf.Tensor

    """
    shape = tuple(arr.get_shape().as_list())
    rank_ = len(shape)
    N, d = shape[-2:]

    # Build a prefix from the array without the indices we'll use later.
    pref = string.ascii_lowercase[:rank_ - 2]

    # Outer product of points (..., N, N)
    xxT = tf.einsum('{0}ni,{0}mi->{0}nm'.format(pref), arr, arr)

    # Inner product of points. (..., N)
    xTx = tf.einsum('{0}ni,{0}ni->{0}n'.format(pref), arr, arr)

    # (..., N, N) inner products tiled.
    xTx_tile = tf.tile(xTx[..., None], (1,) * (rank_ - 1) + (N,))

    # Build the permuter. (sigh, no tf.swapaxes yet)
    permute = list(range(rank_))
    permute[-2], permute[-1] = permute[-1], permute[-2]

    # dists = (x^Tx - 2x^Ty + y^Tx)^(1/2). Note the axis swapping is necessary to 'pair' x^Tx and y^Ty
    return tf.sqrt(xTx_tile - 2 * xxT + tf.transpose(xTx_tile, permute))
```

Comment: Your solutions work fine for me except that I sometimes get NaN out of the calculation. The value under sqrt becomes negative. I am passing a (K, N, N) dimensional array to the function.