# Tensorflow - Can't convert Operation to Tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to compute the pairwise Euclidean distance between the output of an Operation and a Tensor. I'm using code suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43839120/compute-the-pairwise-distance-between-each-pair-of-the-two-collections-of-inputs). Here's the gist of my code:

```
    # Suppose logits has shape [32, 128]
    logits = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name('Tanh')
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[10, 128])

    m1, m2, k = 32, tf.shape(y)[0], latent_dim

    # Get the pairwise distances
    p1 = tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(logits), 1), 1),
                  tf.ones(shape=(1, m2)))
    p2 = tf.transpose(tf.matmul(
        tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y), 1), shape=[-1, 1]),
        tf.ones(shape=(m1, 1)),
        transpose_b=True
    ))
    distance_predictions = tf.sqrt(tf.add(p1, p2) - 2 * 
         tf.matmul(logits, y, transpose_b=True))
```

However I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert Operation '.../Tanh' to Tensor (target dtype=None, name=u'x', as_ref=False)
```

For this line:

```
p1 = tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(logits), 1), 1),
              tf.ones(shape=(1, m2)))
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: What line raises the error?

Comment: Edited my question!

Comment: Could you please show us MCVE(https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? I have tried to reproduce your error but for my scenario everything worked fine.

Comment: The logits operation was being loaded from a previously saved graph, so the actual line is `logits = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name('Tanh')` and hence not very reproducible. I've figured out how to fix this though, as stated below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By calling `tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name`, I was getting the ops that calculated the tanh activation. But what I need instead is the output of that operation, which I can find by calling `tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name`.

Hence the fix is to replace the first line with

`logits = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('Tanh:0')`