# How to get Pairwise Euclidean Distance of Two tensors (shape=[?,256,512]) inside of Lambda layer in tensorflow keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I have two tensors of shape (?,256,512). My aim is to calculate the Pairwise Euclidean Distance along axis=2 (third axis). I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43839120/compute-the-pairwise-distance-between-each-pair-of-the-two-collections-of-inputs?fbclid=IwAR0YnmM3JAisf29kdmfknIJYw-VEH8tZ1QG5ekerR13zdpIYWFbdUB9t--M) solution. In this solution they used 2-D tensors of known shape (e.g: (2,3)). However, in my case, I am trying to build a custom layer using input shapes of both (?,256,512) where ?=batch number, 256=feature number and 512=feature depth. The expected output shape is (256,256).

The problem I am facing is due to the '?' in the mentioned shapes while building the model. I am looking for a solution that can be implemented specifically using tensorflow.